# How do I get file outputs of gradle task

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I want to create a gradle task in Android Studio that will do something with the output of the build task of another project

```
task foo {
   dependsOn ':someApp:build'
   ...
   copy results of :someApp:build to another location
   ...
}
```

I can't just hardcode a path as I won't know if `someApp` was built as `debug` or `release` and the output paths will vary based on the type of build.

Answer (score 0):

dynamic copy task without using hardcoded path.

```
applicationVariants.all {
        variant->
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                println("..a")
                task "copy${variant.buildType.name}"(type:Copy){
                    println("${variant.buildType.name}")
                    dependsOn app:assembleDebug

                    copy {
                        from "$buildDir\\outputs\\apk\\${variant.buildType.name}\\app-${variant.buildType.name}.apk"
                        into "C:\\Users\\rkumar8\\AndroidStudioProjects\\MyApplication\\app\\build\\outputs\\apk\\"
                    }
// you can add multiple copy if required, i am doing it here release build was named app-release-unsigned.apk
                    copy {
                        from "$buildDir\\outputs\\apk\\${variant.buildType.name}\\app-${variant.buildType.name}-unsigned.apk"
                        into "C:\\Users\\rkumar8\\AndroidStudioProjects\\MyApplication\\app\\build\\outputs\\apk\\"
                    }


                }

            }
    }
```

Comment: This is so verbose, and moves all of the logic away from where it needs to be.  There must be a more straight forward way to do this (sidenote, this example depends on assembleDebug which is not buildType agnostic)

Answer (score -1):

I added a task in android block of build.gradle of app module.

```
applicationVariants.all {
        variant->
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                println("..a")
                task "copy${variant.buildType.name}"(type:Copy){
                    println("${variant.buildType.name}")
                    dependsOn app:assembleDebug

                    copy {
                        from "$buildDir\\outputs\\apk\\${variant.buildType.name}\\app-${variant.buildType.name}.apk"
                        into "C:\\Users\\rkumar8\\AndroidStudioProjects\\MyApplication\\app\\build\\outputs\\apk\\"
                    }
// you can add multiple copy if required, i am doing it here release build was named app-release-unsigned.apk
                    copy {
                        from "$buildDir\\outputs\\apk\\${variant.buildType.name}\\app-${variant.buildType.name}-unsigned.apk"
                        into "C:\\Users\\rkumar8\\AndroidStudioProjects\\MyApplication\\app\\build\\outputs\\apk\\"
                    }


                }

            }
    }
```

2. There is another post for adding our task in android build path.
   https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-insert-my-task-into-a-pre-defined-build-android-build/29685/3

Comment: This uses a hard coded path to the debug directory.  I want to be able to copy based on whether I'm building the debug OR the release (or any other buildType) for that matter.