# How to aggregate test reports in android multi-module gradle project in 2019

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, android-gradle-plugin, multi-module

I have a multi-module Android gradle project.

```
project
  |- app
  |- module1
  |- module2
```

Each of the modules contains unit tests, the `app` module also contains Instrumented Tests. Instead of taking the xml reports from the modules I would like to store them in one place, e.g. `/build/tests/reports`.

What I tried so far to achieve this is to set the report dir to this path

```
android {
    testOptions {
        resultsDir "$rootDir/build/test/results"
        reportDir "$rootDir/build/test/reports"
    }
}
```

I applied this in all the module's gradle files. But it seems as if this only works for the instrumented / `connected` test reports. How can I also achieve this for unit tests?

Comment: You want it all test reports into one file or all test reports as different file but in one directory? In second case you can use copyTask. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56896536/4181904

Comment: One directory - ok, thanks for the tip